# Subtracting the total of one column from another - PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

What I'm trying to do is subtract the total of one entire MySQL column from the total of another entire column. I *can* successfully sum both of the columns individually, but I can't bridge the gap between adding them both up and then subtracting one column from the other.

```
$start = "SELECT SUM(start) FROM `table`";
$end = "SELECT SUM(end) FROM `table`";
$total = "Here is my problem"; //I tried something like $end - $start, but to no avail
```

I can display the sum of start and the sum of end, but can't take end - start.

Comment: in theory `SELECT SUM(start) as START, SUM(end) as END, (SUM(end)-SUM(start)) as SUB FROM table` ___SHOULD___ work

Comment: `Select Sum(End) - Sum(Start) From Table`   I'm a wizard.

Comment: @Siyual same as mine but I added the other two incase he needed those seperately also.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT (SUM(start) - SUM(end)) AS `difference` FROM `table`
```

Comment: Hmm, all of these might work. Forgive my noobish-ness, but once I set that as my $total variable, how can I display that? I have
 echo "Total: ". $total; and that displays the query on the page

Comment: You know they have to be run through a database extension, right? If you weren't aware, check out: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: No I know that and have connected to the database and all that with no problems. I don't have a 'total' column in my database though as I was hoping I would be able to just display the 'end' column - the 'start' as the total without making a 'total' column in the database, because I didn't want users to see the 'total' unless they went to a specific page. Is that doable or do I have to make a 'total' column?

Comment: It's up to you what to display. Using an alias (SELECT ... AS total) will let you access the 'total' key in the result array, despite not being a field name, if that's what you're asking?

Comment: Yeah ok that makes total sense, so if I use 'total' as an alias, how can I echo that out? I understand the query, I now need to display the query results if that makes sense.

Comment: The same way you would with any field name, which is dependent on your DB driver/extension. (e.g. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Answer (score 0):

I guess even this would work:

```
SELECT SUM(`start` -`end`) AS `total` FROM `table`
```

Answer (score 0):

As described by others you can select the sum already calculated

```
$totalsql = "SELECT (SUM(start) - SUM(end)) AS difference FROM table";
//Query to call would be here $result = $db->query($totalsql) or whatever
$total = $result['difference'];
```